# How to union alphabets?

Tags: python, union

How to union two sets of alphabets in python without changing their order?

For example:

```
String1: 'PEACH'   Set1={'P','E','A','C','H'}
String2: 'DUE'    
Set2={'D','U','E'}
Output Set1 union Set2 = {'P','E','A','D','U'}
```

Comment: Why no 'C' or 'H' in the union?

Comment: What if the intersection of the strings doesn't occur in the same order for both strings?

Comment: What's rule and what do you try?

Comment: If order is important, you can't use sets; they don't have order.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code is invalid for python.
2. Sets do not have order by definition of [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)
3. Probably, you need to use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) data structure

Following snippet shows an example:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> first_keys = OrderedDict.fromkeys('PEACH')  
>>> first_keys.keys()
['P', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'H']
>>> second_keys = OrderedDict.fromkeys('DUE')
>>> second_keys.keys()
['D', 'U', 'E']
>>> first_keys.update(second_keys.items())
>>> first_keys.keys()
['P', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'H', 'D', 'U']
```

Answer (score 2):

Concat the two strings, and apply `OrderedDict.fromkeys`. With `s1` and `s2` as your strings:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s1+s2))
['P', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'H', 'D', 'U']
```